# How to add links to CMS page on default magento header in magento2

Tags: magento2, cms, headerlink

I had created a About US cms page from Admin panel(Content->Pages)

Now, i want to add link to this CMs page in the header of my website.

[image]

In the above image i want to add "About Us" link next to "CONTACT US".

This is my xml code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">111</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">50</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="about-porto">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">About Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about-porto</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you share your xml code ..

Comment: Have u try my answer ? ?

Comment: @Magento_Bhurio  ....No, its not working

Comment: @aravind. Tried your code too, its not working....See my edited post i  have added my default.xml file

Comment: Please Try My Updated answer.

Comment: If helped to u please accept my answer, for helping other users.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file add follwoing code to display about us link,

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
            <arguments>
                  <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
      </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Yes your solution worked....Thanx

Comment: You are welocme..

Comment: I think i missed to change header.links to top.links

Answer (score 1):

Please look at here it's simple 
Your xml Page Shold Like this one
in your custom theme, please add this code in this file :-

> project/app/design/frontend/Magento/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/defualt.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">111</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">50</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="about-us">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">About Us</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about-porto</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
    </referenceBlock>
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
</body>
```